# ¿Como evitar o minimizar el parpadeo de un componente en WinForms C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, component

Estoy realizando un proyecto usando winforms y para ello necesito agregar un flowLayoutPanel el cual contendra varios botones pero el detalle es que al ser muchos y no querer que ocupen todo el espacio de la ventana active en las propiedades del flowLayoutPanel el autoScroll y aqui me di cuenta que al usarlo todos los botones empiezan a parpadear, entonces me gustaria preguntarles si hay alguna manera de poder reducir o eliminar este parpadeo que ocurre al hacer el scroll?

Asi es como tengo el diseño y son 12 botones:
[image: Ejemplo]

Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

PD: Realmente no estoy usando codigo, solo son los componentes que agregue de la caja de herramientas.

Comment: mmmmm, agrega una foto para ver como lo tienes y señala cuantos botones son en total

Comment: @Yussef Listo, cabe mencionar que estoy usando el framework `Material Skin 2` para los botones, el flowLayoutPanel es del sistema

Comment: Hice la prueba con 100 botones y no me da ningún parpadeo. Lo que si noto es que se encendió el ventilador del procesador, al menos en la ventana de diseño, por lo que supongo que esos botones pueden ser más pesados de lo que uno recomendaría para un botón y de ahí nace tu problema, pero es solo una suposición

Comment: @Yussef Al parecer si son los botones, los cambie por los que trae el sistema y no me da parpadeo, solo son con los del framework... entonces solo quedaria usar los del sistema? no hay manera de acomodar los otros?

Comment: Yo probaría en otro computador, quizás tu andas bajo de recursos en el tuyo.  Pero lo mejor es que busques otra librería, esta está descontinuada de hace años y cerraron los `issues` en el github como para buscar si el problema se daba en otros usuarios.

Comment: Además puedes cambiar el estilo del botón nativo, para que se parezca al que quieres usar, es cosa retocar el fondo, el borde y la letra